# How to remove sourceMappingURL from the angular universal build?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I'm using [this repo as base.](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) I have solved almost every other plugin's errors but I'm not able to solve this error.

No other plugin expects a .map file when making an SSR build as it is a production one. But I don't know from where is it creeping in.

Here is the line causing the error. in `server.js` file.

```
margin: -1px 0; }\n\n/*# sourceMappingURL=swiper.component.css.map
```

I don't want to remove it manually every time I make a build so how to solve the issue and what the issue could be.

> ERROR Something went wrong please try again later! ERROR { Error:
>   Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'swiper.component.css.map' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment: 'swiper.component.css.map' at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError
>   (E:\xampp\htdocs\havemybooks\dist\server.js:146214:16) at
>   CatchSubscriber.selector
>   (E:\xampp\htdocs\havemybooks\dist\server.js:146195:29) at
>   CatchSubscriber.error
>   (E:\xampp\htdocs\havemybooks\dist\server.js:29486:31) at
>   MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error
>   (E:\xampp\htdocs\havemybooks\dist\server.js:20931:26)

*Update:*

I found the culprit it's the plugin which has inline `/*# sourceMappingURL=swiper.component.css.map */`
So is there a webpack configuration to replace the inline sourcemaps already present.

I tried `--devtool false` with webpack but no success

Comment: try removing `\n\n` (`margin: -1px 0; }/*# sourceMappingURL=swiper.component.css.map`)

Comment: Yes, that will fix the issue. But I don't want to do it manually every time I make a build.

Comment: I think its that component for simplifying code and build with less space that put `\n\n` in this line. Try to look some configuration to that component (forget the name of it)

Answer (score 8):

This is a bug in angular cli. But you can manually specify to not to produce source maps in `angular.json` file.

```
"server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            ...
            "sourceMap": false
          },
         ...
 }
```

Comment: I think it is there by default in production build. So specifying it doesn't affect a much.